# why nothing happens when filling Rect with color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

the following code is called right after clicking a button and adding new ViewController using pushViewController. the code is inside the new view controller that was just added.

```
- (void)setColorTable
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        [[self view] setNeedsLayout];
        [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];

        float x = _colorBar.frame.origin.x;
        float y = _colorBar.frame.origin.y;


        CGRect bigRect = CGRectMake(x, y, _colorBar.frame.size.width, _colorBar.frame.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bigRect.size);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();                
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextFillRect(context, bigRect);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    });
}
```

Comment: the color bar is inside the view and it is empty UIView

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to draw with no luck! trying to understand the concept

Comment: Where you need to fill Yello Color ??? in ColorBar or in color table ?

Comment: i edited the code, ignore colorTable

Comment: The concepts of drawing in iOS are described in the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). View programming may also be relevant and is described in the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). Also refer the to related documents linked in those guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not draw $vereywhere in your code. You mark a region of the view as needed to be drawn by sending `needToDrawRect:` and then draw inside your custom `-drawRect:` implementation like so:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)unionRectToDraw
{
  // maybe: [super drawRect:unionRectToDraw];
  float x = _colorBar.frame.origin.x;
  float y = _colorBar.frame.origin.y;

  CGRect bigRect = CGRectMake(x, y, _colorBar.frame.size.width, _colorBar.frame.size.height);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bigRect.size);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();                
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);  
  CGContextFillRect(context, bigRect);
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```